# Fortran placement of format statement inside loop

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

In most codes, I see that the FORMAT statement is placed outside the loop, just after the CONTINUE statement in DO loops. I like to place it inside the DO loop, just after the READ or WRITE statements. I am not sure if it effects the speed or causes any confusion. What is the best practice on where to place the FORMAT statement: inside the loop or outside?
Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

Let me state the (somewhat traditional) argument against using format strings in `write` statements.

Put all the format statements used within a compilation unit in a block somewhere (traditional location was at the end) in the same unit.

This way the same format can be used in multiple write statements without redundant repetition. This also makes coordinating format statements expected to be used together (*eg* a table header, column headers and column data formats) much simpler.  The practice of putting format strings in `write` statements becomes a problem when a format, used in multiple places, has to change.  Sprinkling (identical) format strings around a code is a bit like using multiple occurrences of a literal value for, say, `pi`.  Far better practice to define once in one place.

As for putting `format` statements inside loops, my opinion is that it is a bizarre idea without merit.  Since a `format` statement is much more like a declaration than an executable statement it has no place being encountered multiple times during the execution of a code.  If proximity to the place it is used is important to you then put it either before or after the loop.

Does the location of a `format` statement have an impact on the performance of a code ?  One, I expect any decent compiler to deal with (constant) `format` statements at compile-time and to impose no run-time load.  Two, if it matters to you to know more, then set up some tests and measure the impact of the location of the `format` statements.

Finally, yes one can use character parameters to contain format strings and use those in `write` statements.  I've yet to be persuaded that this approach is anything other than stylistically different to using `format` statements.  And the traditional approach makes it obvious that the strings are format strings.

If you've read this far, read @IanH's comment below, it makes a couple of good points about advantages of string constants over `format` statements.

Comment: You can give a named character constant or variable a name that gives a good hint at what its contained format specification might do.  You cannot do that with a numeric statement label.  Named character constants and variables can be use and host associated.  Format statements cannot.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanations. Indeed, the format statement is pretty useful for some specific cases as you described. I like versatility and use it to great extend. I will have to test the speed issues when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is not to use FORMAT statements, but to put the format string as a character constant into the WRITE or PRINT statement itself. This keeps the reader from having to jump to another statement when trying to understand what the code does.

So, instead of writing

```
  WRITE (55,9000) A

 9000 FORMAT (4G12.5)
```

you should write

```
 WRITE (55,'(4G12.5)') A
```

Comment: Thanks and yes I agree. I am modifying some existing code, in which all format statements are outside the do loops. I was just wondering if there is some merit to it that I am not aware of. From your answer, I understand putting it closest to the calling statement (read/write) is better than putting it all the way outside the loop and should not make any speed difference but putting it into the statement itself is better. Thanks again.